# How do I determine the first screen to open according to a bool variable

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing a project with Swift UIKit and I have a variable called `islogin` and I want to redirect the user to the homepage if it comes true according to this `islogin`. `islogin` comes true but it still throws me to the register screen. Where do you think my mistake is?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let isLogin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogin")
    print("uygulama açılırken " , isLogin)

    if isLogin {
        print(isLogin)
        let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeMenuViewContr = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeMenuViewController") as! HomeMenuViewController
        homeMenuViewContr.userName = username
        window?.rootViewController = homeMenuViewContr
        print("calisti")
    } else {
        print("else kısmı " ,isLogin)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginViewContr = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewContr)
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    }
    
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

[image]

Ho provato a fare questo metodo usando la funzione di applicazione in AppDelegate ma non ha funzionato, non mi lancia mai alla homepage

Comment: Please edit your question so it is only in English. SO is an English-only website.

Answer (score 0):

***1st way***

Remove code from `AppDelegate` and copy it into `SceneDelegate` :

```
func scene (_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)  {

   guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        window.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

---

***2nd way***

If you dont want a SceneDelegate file then follow below steps:

1.-> Firstly delete SceneDelegate file.

2.-> Go to info.plist, then under "Application Scene
Manifest" there is "Scene Configuration". Remove that row.

3.-> Now go to AppDelegate file, under that there are two UISceneSession Lifecycle delegate functions. Remove those.

4.-> Run the project again, it will work as you want.